# C - Function not returning value?

Tags: c

I have the following method defined in my header file

```
unsigned char test(void);
```

Implementation:

```
unsigned char test()
{
  unsigned char value = 0xFF;
  return value;    
}
```

When I call it with this:

```
 unsigned char temp;
 temp = test();
```

Nothing is returned???  I stepped through it with breakpoints.  At the very end, the variable value has a value of 0xFF, but it is never returned to temp?

I am not used to plain old C... only C++, there might be some kind of subtle difference in how methods are declared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: How do you know it isn't returned to `temp`?  Do you mean that when you e.g. print `temp` to the console, its value is not `0x49`?  What value does it have?

Comment: It's very much unclear what you mean by "is never returned to temp". Please explain what the exact problem is.

Comment: The code you present will return the value. Please could you post the real code, the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code as listed. Perhaps showing more would be a good idea. As far as functions go, C and C++ are the same at that level.

Comment: Hello everyone, I have edited my code to a new function implemented in my c file.  This is EXACT code.  I am stepping through line by line, when the function returns to temp, it is not copying the value over.  Temp is showing up in my debug window as being 0x00.

Comment: Are you running your debugger past the assignment line?  GDB at least does not execute the line you are looking at until you go past it.

Comment: Could you please print the value of `temp` after it is returned from `test()`. Unused variables can sometimes be optimized out by the compiler. Generally speaking good old `printf` is always the most reliable method.

Comment: @Dave: Can you confirm that if you do e.g. `printf("%d\n", temp);`, you see `0` on the console?

Comment: Hello,  This is a low level processor so no I cant printF because I don't see a console on my IDE and YES I am stepping past the line.

Comment: Is there any way you can post the assembled code?

Comment: And to be even more clear, it is now actually saying that temp is not allocated instead of saying 0x00, sorry for confusion.  I've never had this issue before, chars are always processed correctly by my IDE.

Comment: Well if you can't printf, you could write something like `if (test == 0) throw whatever`. This is still more reliable than a debugger.

Comment: Hello, everyone, I have solved the issue by declaring the temp variable as a global instead of at the top of main.  WHY would this solve it???  Moving it back to main breaks the program, why is that?  I have heard that C variables always have to be declared at the top of a function, which I had done in main.

Comment: Hello, everyone, I have solved the issue by declaring the temp variable as a global instead of at the top of main.  WHY would this solve it???

Moving it back to main breaks the program again... what in the world?

Comment: Apparently debugging global variables is easier than local variables. Global variables have a fixed position in memory so debugger hardly ever gets confused by that.

Comment: I did the above IF statement trick, and it would not go inside.  Thus, it is not the debuggers fault.

Comment: EDIT:  I did the above IF statement trick, and it would not go inside. Thus, it is not the debuggers fault.

Comment: What exactly have you tested? You tested for the value you expect, I understand?

Comment: I tested for any value other that zero, if(value)

Answer (score 6):

I think you just see a clever compiler. If your variable is never used after the assignment it is just optimized out. The function is still called for its possible side effect, though.

If you change your variable to a global, the compiler can't know that you will not use it, so it does the assignment, then.

I think if you'd put a `printf` after the assignment or declare your `tmp` variable `volatile` you'd observe the assignment in the debugger as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sure its not user error of debugger?
Most debuggers wont show the value of the variable "temp" until the next line of code, when the assignment has actually been performed.

Comment: Hello, as stated above in comments I am stepping well past the line of code.  I do not believe it is an IDE error as I have always had success showing char values.

Comment: Seriously, don't believe - just test it instead. Place some code that is dependent on the value of `temp` and see if the behaviour is appropriate. Also disabling optimization might help the debugger.

Comment: Odd. Out of curiosity, what compiler are you using?
I've tried every compiler flag I can think of, I get a value in temp when printing it.

Comment: I have solved it, see that answer below.  I do not know why it did it so I wish someone could explain to me.

Answer (score 2):

If optimizations are enabled, temp may be kept in a register, and sometimes debuggers will have trouble finding and displaying these values. Actually, the compiler could very well discard the return value if you don't use it anywhere. Make sure your code is compiled without any optimizations for debug purposes.

Alternatively, use the oldest method known to men for debugging: `printf`. :)

Answer (score 0):

It the function call has been optimized away by your compiler, the compiler noticed that you are doing nothing with temp and your function call has no side effects, so it optimized it out.

Try adding a printf after doing `temp = test();` the compiler will no perform the same optimization again.